# Индикатор Caps Lock в Vim

Tags: vim

Начал изучать Vim. Выяснилось, что при использовании горячих клавиш в нормальном режиме есть разница между клавишами в нижнем и верхнем регистре. Но на ноуте нигде нет лампочек, отображающих включенность Caps Lock, так что трудно быстро определять, что вводить.

Уверен Vim достаточно продвинутый редактор, чтобы в нем был индикатор Caps Lock.

Вопрос: как его включить? Не могу это нагуглить.

Comment: Что это за ноут такой?

Answer (score 0):

Caps Lock - зло, которое осталось со времен динозавров. Под динозаврами я имею ввиду печатные машинки. На сегодняшний день нет причин для ее использования (уж не говоря о том, что она занимает место в домашнем ряду. Раз уж вы стали использовать `vim`, то логичнее было бы перенести клавишу `ctr` на место `caps lock`, а последнюю вообще не использовать. В линуксе это можно сделать просто через настройки клавиатуры.